# Kafka Consumer stuck in rebalancing state

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

We are having a Kafka consumer, which all of a sudden(without any activity) went into a rebalancing state and got stuck. This caused the CPU of the k8 pod to shoot and GC time was also nearly 70-80%. The node didn't recover from that state. Upon deleting all the topics, it recovered after almost 4-5 hours.

Kafka version - 2.1.1
No of topics - 520( with 10 partitions each)
Consumer groups - 1
partition assignment strategy - sticky

Attaching some of the info logs here at that time.

```
2021-10-12 10:41:21 
2021-10-12 05:11:21.160   INFO 6 CID:  UID:  RID: --- [cation_consumer] s.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator : [Consumer clientId=consumer-staging_notification_consumer-10, groupId=staging_notification_consumer] Member consumer-staging_notification_consumer-10-8a7eb399-c4e0-4443-b330-bfac42ca89ae sending LeaveGroup request to coordinator kafka5:9092 (id: 2147483642 rack: null) due to consumer poll timeout has expired. This means the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time processing messages. You can address this either by increasing max.poll.interval.ms or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.


2021-10-12 05:10:27.340   INFO 6 CID:4967  UID:  RID:17c72e2d517-4d5e --- [ntainer#9-0-C-1] s.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator : [Consumer clientId=consumer-staging_notification_consumer-9, groupId=staging_notification_consumer] Giving away all assigned partitions as lost since generation has been reset,indicating that consumer is no longer part of the group


2021-10-12 10:40:27 
2021-10-12 05:10:27.340   INFO 6 CID:4967  UID:  RID:17c72e2d517-4d5e --- [ntainer#9-0-C-1] s.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator : [Consumer clientId=consumer-staging_notification_consumer-9, groupId=staging_notification_consumer] Lost previously assigned partitions staging_notification_topic_app_low_mobi_3119-4, staging_notification_topic_app_low_mobi_2023-4, staging_notification_topic_app_low_mobi_5170-9, staging_notification_topic_app_low_mobi_3540-9, staging_notification_topic_app_low_mobi_5722-9,


2021-10-12 10:40:37 
2021-10-12 05:10:37.247   INFO 6 CID:  UID:  RID: --- [cation_consumer] s.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator : [Consumer clientId=consumer-staging_notification_consumer-12, groupId=staging_notification_consumer] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
2021-10-12 10:40:37 
2021-10-12 05:10:37.183   INFO 6 CID:  UID:  RID: --- [cation_consumer] s.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator : [Consumer clientId=consumer-staging_notification_consumer-10, groupId=staging_notification_consumer] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing


2021-10-12 10:40:57 
2021-10-12 05:10:57.435   INFO 6 CID:  UID:  RID: --- [cation_consumer] s.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator : [Consumer clientId=consumer-staging_notification_consumer-10, groupId=staging_notification_consumer] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
2021-10-12 10:40:57 
2021-10-12 05:10:57.435   INFO 6 CID:  UID:  RID: --- [cation_consumer] s.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator : [Consumer clientId=consumer-staging_notification_consumer-12, groupId=staging_notification_consumer] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing



2021-10-12 10:41:56 
2021-10-12 05:11:56.922   INFO 6 CID:4967  UID:  RID:17c72e2579c-22e6 --- [ntainer#9-3-C-1] s.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator : [Consumer clientId=consumer-staging_notification_consumer-12, groupId=staging_notification_consumer] Failing OffsetCommit request since the consumer is not part of an active group
2021-10-12 10:41:56 
2021-10-12 05:11:56.923  ERROR 6 CID:4967  UID:  RID:17c72e2579c-22e6 --- [ntainer#9-3-C-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer : Consumer exception
2021-10-12 10:41:56 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This error handler cannot process 'org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException's; no record information is available
2021-10-12 10:41:56 
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekUtils.seekOrRecover(SeekUtils.java:151)
2021-10-12 10:41:56 
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.handle(SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.java:113)
2021-10-12 10:41:56 
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.handleConsumerException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1427)
2021-10-12 10:41:56 
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1124)
2021-10-12 10:41:56 
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
2021-10-12 10:41:56 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2021-10-12 10:41:56 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-10-12 10:41:56 
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Offset commit cannot be completed since the consumer is not part of an active group for auto partition assignment; it is likely that the consumer was kicked out of the group.
2021-10-12 10:41:56 
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.sendOffsetCommitRequest(ConsumerCoordinator.java:1134)
2021-10-12 10:41:56 
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.commitOffsetsSync(ConsumerCoordinator.java:999)
2021-10-12 10:41:56 
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.commitSync(KafkaConsumer.java:1504)
2021-10-12 10:41:56 
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doCommitSync(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2396)
2021-10-12 10:41:56 
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.commitSync(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2391)
2021-10-12 10:41:56 
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.commitIfNecessary(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2377)
2021-10-12 10:41:56 
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.processCommits(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2191)
2021-10-12 10:41:56 
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1149)
2021-10-12 10:41:56 
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1075)
2021-10-12 10:41:56 
    ... 3 common frames omitted


2021-10-12 10:41:58 
2021-10-12 05:11:58.442   INFO 6 CID:4967  UID:  RID:17c72e2579c-22e6 --- [ntainer#9-3-C-1] s.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator : [Consumer clientId=consumer-staging_notification_consumer-12, groupId=staging_notification_consumer] Giving away all assigned partitions as lost since generation has been reset,indicating that consumer is no longer part of the group


021-10-12 10:58:36  
2021-10-12 05:28:36.039   INFO 6 CID:4412  UID:  RID:17c72ebadab-64d7 --- [ntainer#3-1-C-1] s.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator : [Consumer clientId=consumer-staging_notification_consumer-17, groupId=staging_notification_consumer] Join group failed with org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RebalanceInProgressException: The group is rebalancing, so a rejoin is needed.
2021-10-12 10:58:36 
2021-10-12 05:28:36.044   INFO 6 CID:4412  UID:  RID:17c72ebadab-64d7 --- [ntainer#3-1-C-1] s.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator : [Consumer clientId=consumer-staging_notification_consumer-17, groupId=staging_notification_consumer] (Re-)joining group

021-10-12 10:58:36  
2021-10-12 05:28:36.039   INFO 6 CID:4412  UID:  RID:17c72ebadab-64d7 --- [ntainer#3-1-C-1] s.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator : [Consumer clientId=consumer-staging_notification_consumer-17, groupId=staging_notification_consumer] Join group failed with org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RebalanceInProgressException: The group is rebalancing, so a rejoin is needed.
2021-10-12 10:58:36 
2021-10-12 05:28:36.044   INFO 6 CID:4412  UID:  RID:17c72ebadab-64d7 --- [ntainer#3-1-C-1] s.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator : [Consumer clientId=consumer-staging_notification_consumer-17, groupId=staging_notification_consumer] (Re-)joining group




2021-10-12 11:05:36 
2021-10-12 05:35:36.955   INFO 6 CID:3435  UID:  RID:17c72f29913-886c --- [ntainer#7-3-C-1] s.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator : [Consumer clientId=consumer-staging_notification_consumer-5, groupId=staging_notification_consumer] Join group failed with org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException
```

This was resolved when I deleted the topics.

**Similar behaviour** is observed when I increase the number of threads in concurrent listener factory, the consumer fails to come up with similar logs of constant rebalancing

Answer (score 0):

The **first log** indicates that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured **max.poll.interval.ms** (five minutes default).

When this happens, the consumer client will actively initiate a **LeaveGroup** request to the coordinator to **trigger rebalance**.

You can address this either by increasing max.poll.interval.ms or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.

Of course, a better way is to check the reason for the slow processing of the program and optimize it.

Comment: Yes, but the real issue is that the rebalancing gets stuck after the timeout. And this was resolved only when the topics were deleted.